# Passing fields from parent view model to child (partial) view MVC + Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `GroupPageViewModel` that has a `public string GroupName { get; }` and an input model for a service method `EditGroupInputModel` that also has a `public string GroupName { get; set; }`.

In the view for the page, I would like to render the editor for `Group`, a la `Html.Partial("~/Views/Group/_EditGroup.cshtml", ???)` or using `EditorFor`.

I would like for the `model` for `_EditGroup.cshtml` to be the `EditGroupInputModel`, but it needs to know `GroupName` from the parent view's `GroupName` property.

I realize that I could use `Html.Partial("~/Views/Group/_EditGroup.cshtml", new EditGroupInputModel() { GroupName = Model.GroupName})` , but I feel like this somehow deviates from the intent of the MVC framework (or I just haven't seen an example like this).

Is this the "best-practice" way to pass such a parameter to the partial view's model, or is there a better approach with the MVC framework?

Comment: Could you not create a ParentGroupName property in EditGroupInputModel?  Then you would just pass the model to your partial view: Html.Partial("~/Views/Group/_EditGroup.cshtml", model.EditGroupInputModel)

Comment: @markpsmith, it is not a given that every `GroupPageViewModel` should have an `EditGroupInputModel` (editing is only one of many actions you can do, for argument's sake)

Comment: Ah ok,  I think I misunderstood

Comment: While building your model classes Make use of the `{get;set;}` properties of the EditGroupInputModel.GroupName view model. In set you can make this.GroupName = base.GroupName  something like this. I am not sure with the syntax but A per I know you have to play with the {get;set}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imho there's nothing wrong with

```
Html.Partial("~/Views/Group/_EditGroup.cshtml", new EditGroupInputModel() { GroupName = Model.GroupName})
```

I usually pass the model of parent view in constructor, so it's up to child model to decide what it needs:

View:

```
Html.Partial("~/Views/Group/_EditGroup.cshtml", new EditGroupInputModel(Model))
```

EditGroupInputModel.cs:

```
EditGroupInputModel(GroupPageViewModel parentModel) 
{ 
    GroupName = parentModel.GroupName;
}
```